# Valgrind - problem with held broken packages

Tags: installation, dependencies

When I try to install Valgrind with `sudo apt-get install valgrind`, I get error:

```
valgrind : Depends: libc6-dbg but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there any (safe) solution for this?
I have Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a list of actual held packages with:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

Another method of troubleshooting may be to use `aptitude` rather than `apt-get` to try to install your package:

```
sudo aptitude install valgrind
```

Aptitude will give up less easily, and will attempt to find solutions which may involve modifying other packages. It may give you more explanation of the problem and options for fixing it.

[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Had to install aptitude first, and then install valgrind with aptitude. Some packages had to be downgraded for valgrind to work...

Answer (score 0):

Install libc6-dbg package like this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg
```

and then install valgrind

```
sudo apt-get install valgrind
```