# Packages have unmet dependencies on Ubuntu sdk installation

Tags: 13.04, application-development, ubuntu-touch

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-sdk : Depends: qtcreator but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: qtdeclarative5-qtaudioengine-plugin but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am using ubuntu 13.04 x64

Comment: Please provide **full** and **exact** output of the command in your question (edit it). What exact dependencies are failing? And include the Ubuntu version you're using (`lsb_release -a`)

Comment: Please **edit** your question to include the information. As you can see, comments aren't fit for that. All information relevant to your question belongs **in your question**. This site is not a forum, but a Q&A site.

Comment: This seems to be quite similar to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/297244/valgrind-problem-with-held-broken-packages). Please tell us if the first answer works.